# How we can edit Config XML of BigBlueButton?

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-5.5, bigbluebutton

I have installed BBB 2.0 beta version and its working properly.
I have used [BBB PHP API](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-api-php) package to integrate API in laravel.
I want to set default layout while creating a meeting. Which is not available in the above package. To set default layout we need edit config XML file of BBB.

Any idea how I can do this in Laravel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Stack isn't a place for this kind of question. Go and try something, when you hit a technical problem, come back and ask.

Comment: @Joe so what I asked. Did I ask to sing a song? It is a technical issue and I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The BigBlueButton developers hang out at bigbluebutton-dev Google Groups.  Post your question there and you'll reach the right audience.  See https://bigbluebutton.org/support.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Fred.